# Building a multiplication table with loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Hello all I'm new to programming and as a means of testing what I've learned so far, I decided to give myself the task of building the multiplication table 1 to 10 using the function, loop, and if-else statement but after writing the code, the output is undefined, even tho I passed an argument into the function.

Please help me out...I'm learning alone. Bellow is the piece of code.

```
var a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = 0;
var msgA = "";
var msgB = "";
var msgC = "";
var msgD = "";
var msgE = "";
var msgF = "";
var msgG = "";
var msgH = "";
var msgI = "";
var msgJ = "";

function multipletable( e ) {
    if(a < 11) {
        while (a < 11) {
            msgA += a + 'x 1 = ' + (a * 1) + '<br />'; a++; 
        }
    }
    else if(b < 11){
        while (b < 11) {
            msgB += b + 'X 2 = ' + (b * 2) + '<br />'; b++;
        }
    }
    else if(c < 11){
        while (c < 11) {
            msgC += c + 'X 3 = ' + (c * 3) + '<br />'; c++;
        }
    }
    else if(d < 11){
        while (d < 11) {
            msgD += d + 'X 4 = ' + (d * 4) + '<br />'; d++;
        }
    }
    else if(e < 11){
        while (e < 11) {
            msgE += e + 'X 5 = ' + (e * 5) + '<br />'; e++;
        }
    }
    else if(f < 11){
        while (f < 11) {
            msgF += f + 'X 6 = ' + (f * 6) + '<br />'; f++;
        }
    }
    else if(g < 11){
        while (g < 11) {
            msgG += g + 'X 7 = ' + (g * 7) + '<br />'; g++;
        }
    }
    else if(h < 11){
        while (h < 11) {
            msgH += h + 'X 8 = ' + (h * 8) + '<br />'; h++;
        }
    }
    else if(i < 11){
        while (i < 11) {
            msgI += i + 'X 9 = ' + (i * 9) + '<br />'; i++;
        }
    }
    else if(j < 11){
        while (j < 11) {
            msgj += j + 'X 10 = ' + (j * 10) + '<br />'; j++;
        }
    }
}
console.log(multipletable())
```

Comment: Your function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`. Have you checked that `msgA`, `msgB`, etc contain the values you expect after you call `multipletable()`?

Comment: This code is crying out for **arrays**. Don't define a whole heap of variables with similar, but slightly different names. That's almost always a sign you've missed the mark.

Comment: I'm not sure this code can be salvaged. There's just too much going on here that doesn't actually do anything. Back up and think about this from a more *functional* perspective: Write a function that given *N* and *M* returns the first *N* multiples of *M* in an array. Then write something that coverts that output into your long-form HTML.

Comment: Tip: Use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you can, it's much less mess. `\`X 10 = ${j * 10}<br/>\``